# Find Missing Logs with ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, elastic-stack, log-analysis

I've just deployed ELK in an attempt to see if it can be used for monitoring logs and alerting about issues.

What I need to be able to detect is mostly missing records:
Say a log record was received, saying a user is about to make some sort of request. I then expect to see the log record saying the request has been made.

If the second record was not received within X seconds from the arrival of the first, then something is wrong, and I want to alert about it.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [elapsed{} filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) to do something similar.  With it, you declare the first event and the "matching" event.  If the matching event doesn't appear within a period of time, it will generate an "expired event" that you could check for.